# add + o - match on a string validation

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that validate a value from 00000000 to 9999999999. 
Now I need to add a positive/negative validation from +/-00000000 to +/-9999999999

I use:

```
    /^[0-9]{8,10}$/
```

but can't add the +/- validation I try:

```
    /(-|+)(^[0-9]{8,10})$/
    /[-+](^[0-9]{8,10})$/
    /^[-+][0-9]{8,10}$/
```

how can I validate a string +/-00000000 -> +/-9999999999?

[edit]
using:

```
if (
    !preg_match( "/^[-+]([0-9]{4}).(((0[13578]|(10|12)).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02.(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$/", $_POST[$field] ) ||
    !preg_match( "/^[-+]([0-9]{5,7}).((0[13578]|(10|12))|(02-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$/", $_POST[$field] ) ||
    !preg_match( "/^[-+][0-9]{8,10}$/", $_POST[$field] )
) {
    $this->errors[] = $errorMessage;
}
```

the validation patterns should be:

+/-0000.01.01
+/-9999.12.31

+/-10000.01
+/-9999999.12

+/-10000000
+/-9999999999

it's for date purpose.. 
I get this error:
 Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 3

maybe is because the script attemp to validate also the first and second pattern... 99%

I see also that the pattern validate a +00000000 (8digit) that is wrong because I need to start from +10000000

Comment: The third one should be working... possibly `/^[-+]?[0-9]{8,10}$/`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: the + o - are not optional.. I'm using a preg_match function to validate an input field but none of the three patterns works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if (
    !preg_match("/^[-+][0-9]{4}\.(((0[13578]|(10|12))\.(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))|(02\.(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]))|((0[469]|11)\.(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)))$/", $_POST[$field] ) &&
    !preg_match("/^[-+][1-9][0-9]{4,6}\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/", $_POST[$field] ) &&
    !preg_match("/^[-+][1-9][0-9]{7,9}$/", $_POST[$field] )
) {
    $this->errors[] = $errorMessage;
}
```

Your second regex was trying to match dates and your first regex needed to have escaped periods. I changed some of the ranges to avoid `00000000` like you mentioned.

Other than that, you had misplaced the beginning of line anchors and used `||` instead of `&&` because all three must fail to give the error.

Answer (score 2):

No reason this shouldn't work:

```
<?php
$string = '-0000000000';
$pattern = '/^[-+][0-9]{8,10}$/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
else {
  print 'No matches found.';
}
```

Comment: I found the problem, I'm validating the string with 3 patterns and the problem is on one of the other 2.. this work: /^[-+][0-9]{8,10}$/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your regular expressions, but simpli in the logic of your if statement. You write:

```
if (!preg_match(...) || !preg_match(...) || !preg_match(...)) { ...
```

You should correct to:

```
if (!preg_match(...) && !preg_match(...) && !preg_match(...)) { ...
```

or

```
if (!(preg_match(...) || preg_match(...) || preg_match(...))) { ...
```